# Convert Ruby Array to string with specific format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

This is my array

```
 my_array = ["9999999999", "500", "existingusercheck", "MBK9002", "TestMerchant"]
```

And I want following string as output array

```
 "'9999999999''500''existingusercheck''MBK9002''TestMerchant'"
```

Note: Each value should be quoted with single quote(`'500'`) and whole output should be quoted as string(`""`)

Comment: Could you explain (in the question text), why you are stuck, beyond not immediately knowing the answer yourself. Have you looked at any documentation? Also this is an unusual transformation - are you sure you want to do as written - what is it for?

Comment: array = ["9999999999", "500", "existingusercheck", "MBK9002", "TestMerchant"]
    string = []

    array.each do|aa|
      string << "'#{aa}'"
    end
    output = string.join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
array = ["9999999999", "500", "existingusercheck", "MBK9002", "TestMerchant"]
"'"+array.join("''")+"'"
```